# Multiplying and dividing distributions by non-$C^\infty$ functions.

Tags: distribution-theory

It's quite easy to see that we can multiply distributions by any $\mathcal C^\infty $ functions. Moreover, if the distribution $T$ is of order $k$, then we can mupliply it by a $\mathcal C^k$ function.

The problem is, what to do with division by a function. For example, consider the equation $$|x|S =0,\quad S\in \mathcal D'(\Bbb R).$$
One can show that the support of $S$ is a subset of $\{0\}$. Clearly, we can solve this equation in the class of distributions of order $0$ (easy to see that the solution is $Const\cdot \delta_0$). Then again, for derivatives of $\delta_0$ the expression $|x|\delta_0^{(k)}$ is not even defined (more precisely, it's defined on a subspace of $\mathcal D(\Bbb R)$, but not the whole $\mathcal D(\Bbb R)$). Therefore, we can say that in a certain way we "solved" this incorrectly posed problem.

On the other hand, the equations $|x|S=1$, $|x|S=\delta_0$ don't have solutions (up to some mistake I could have done=)).

So, the question is, is there a criterion for saying that the equation $$|x|S=T$$ has/doesn't have solutions in the class of distributions? And, more generally, if we solve $f(x)S=T$ for $f\in \mathcal C^k\setminus\mathcal C^\infty$?

Comment: Maybe more relevant that $|x|^2$ _is_ smooth, and $|x|^2\cdot u=0$ is "well-posed" for distributions $u$.

Comment: @paulgarrett well, the reasoning for the support of $u$ still holds, we get the solutions $\delta_0$ and $\delta_0'$. Then again, $x^2$ is a $\mathcal C^{\infty}$, so we don't have any problems checking that $\delta_0^{(k)}$ can't be a solution for $k>1$.

Comment: indeed. In effect, one more solution is allowed by replacing $|x|$ with something smooth with the same $0$-set, but things are still under control.

Comment: @paulgarrett, so, what you propose to say, that we solve $x^2S_2=T$, then say that the solution to $|x|S_1=T$ is the $|x|S_2$? But where's the guarantee that $S_2$ is of order $0$?

Comment: I don't think we can do this in steps as you indicate. Indeed, in $\mathbb R^2$ already, $|x|^2\cdot u=0$ has an infinite-dimensional solution space, namely, Fourier transforms of all harmonic polynomials.

Comment: @paulgarrett I don't quite get how your example of $\Bbb R^2$ invalidates these steps. In 1D the dimension of space of solutions of $x^2S=0$ is $2$.

Comment: oh, no, sorry, I didn't mean anything too strong, only that the _order_ the distribution cannot be deduced from the order of vanishing of the function, smooth or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12035/discussion-between-tzakrevskiy-and-paul-garrett)